# Digit Counter Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple java program for counting how many digits a number contains, however I have an issue where the result won't print and I'm having trouble figuring it out. here is the code in my DigitCounter Class:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class DigitCounter
{

private int number;

public void setNum( int num )
{
    number=num;     
}


public int countDigits()
{
    int x=0;
    while(0<number);
    {
        number=number/10;
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}
}
```

Here is my code in the main:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class DigitCounterRunner
```

{

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{


DigitCounter test = new DigitCounter();

    test.setNum(234);
    out.print(test.countDigits());
    out.print(test);

    //add test cases
}
}
```

The problem here is that when i run the program nothing is returned. Sorry if this seems basic Im really new at this.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after `while(0<number)`.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. Thank you it worked